# Give two polynomials in $\mathbb Q[x]$ (of degree 2 and 3) such that their product is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$ of degree 5

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I know that $$x^k - p, \ \ \forall k>0\in N$$

is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$ (Eisenstein theorem). I need two polynomials in $\mathbb Q[x]$ (one of degree 2 and another of degree 3) such that their product is a irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$. Any clue?

Comment: By definition, the product of two nonconstant polynomials is *reducible*.

Comment: So most likely in this exercise I have to point out that it is **not** possible to have such possibility, right? If you want, write this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You might want to read the exercise again. If this is actually what it says, then it's just an uninteresting trick question. Also, usually an exercise will say "if this is possible do it. If it is not, prove it."

Comment: Yes, I should read exercises more carefully. At the top it says "if it is possible". Thank you very much! I appreciate your time helping me.

Comment: If that is from a book, which book is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that is exactly what the exercise says, then the answer is that it is not possible because, by definition, the product of two nonconstant polynomials is *reducible*.